# Zend Framework one route to multiple controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new in Zend Framework and I'm having problem with routes.
I wish to make something like this:

- `http://localhost/category/`
  goes to category controller with no page and city parameter
- `http://localhost/category/page/`
  goes to category with page parameter and no city parameter
- `http://localhost/category/city/`
  goes to category controller with city parameter and no page parameter
- `http://localhost/category/city/page/`
  goes to category controller with city and page parameters
- `http://localhost/city/`
  goes to city controller with no page parameter
- `http://localhost/city/page/`
  goes to city controller with page parameter

p.s. page is paginator param
What i want to do is something like this:

```
localhost/phones/new-york/2 gets second page products form category phones and city New York
localhost/phones/2 gets second page products form category from all cities
localhost/new-york/2 gets second page of all products form city New York and so on...
```

Can I achieve this with standard routes in Zend Framework or have I write custom router?

Is it possible to pass with `$this->url` optional parameters after `?` symbol? I mean something like this:

```
http://localhost/category/city?order_by=category-name&order_asc
```

Comment: what do you mean by city and page parameters? param-name and param-value. You mean, in category controller with city as param name and page as param value?

Comment: I mean page is pagination parameter. I don't know how to make to check if city specified in url exists in db then route goes to city controller, otherwise route goes to category controller and city is just a param (city slug). My goal is to in this case get products form category and current city for example http://localhost/phones/new-york/ i get list of products from category phones and from New York city. (sorry for my bad English :) )

Answer (score 0):

The URL helper will not output query string params as these are not part of the route. Your options are:

Include them on the end:

```
<a href="<?=$this->url(array('controller' => 'category', 'something' => 'city')?>?order_by=category-name&order_asc">Some link</a>
```

or change your routes to use the key/value pairs:

```
http://localhost/:controller/:something/*
```

then, you can do:

```
<a href="<?=$this->url(array('controller' => 'category', 'something' => 'city', 'order_by' => 'category-name', 'order_asc' => 1)?>">Some link</a>
```

which will output:

```
<a href="/category/city/order_by/category-name/order_asc/1">Some link</a>
```